# Interleaving a set of channels during concatenation?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, concatenation, quaternions

I am trying to perform a quaternion space concatenation which requires the four dimensions `r,i,j,k` to be concatenated. According to quaternion theory, we cannot apply the torch.cat function directly as they would mess up the components as `r` channels have to be concatenated with `r` channels and so on. I managed to perform this action using the quaternion_concat function adapted from [here](https://github.com/vanzytay/QuaternionTransformers/blob/master/layers/qlib.py). However, when I use this for networks like densenet, this takes a long time due to multiple for loops concatenations.

Code: Let me give an example, `tensor_1` and `tensor_2` are two tensors that need to be concatenated, and it has 16 channels each. That means it has 4 channels of `r,i,j,k` respectively stacked together. I used the `torch.chunk` function to separate these and concatenate them separately and finally combine them back. Is there any way I could efficiently perform this?

```
import torch

def quarternion_concat(x, dim=2):
    output = [[] for i in range(4)]
    for _x in x:
        sp = torch.chunk(_x, 4, dim=dim)
        for i in range(4):
            output[i].append(sp[i])

    final = []
    for o in output:
        o = torch.cat(o, dim)
        final.append(o)

    return torch.cat(final, dim)


tensor_1 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_2 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)

tensor3 = quarternion_concat([tensor_1, tensor_2], dim=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with an alternative solution which may or may not suit your needs in the function quarternion_concat2 in the code below, where I've used indexing into an array to simply assign the tensors into their correct position in the final array:

```
import torch
from time import time
def quarternion_concat(x, dim=2):
    output = [[] for i in range(4)]
    for _x in x:
        sp = torch.chunk(_x, 4, dim=dim)
        for i in range(4):
            output[i].append(sp[i])

    final = []
    for o in output:
        o = torch.cat(o, dim)
        final.append(o)

    return torch.cat(final, dim)


tensor_1 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_2 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_3 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_4 = torch.randn((1, 16, 256, 256), requires_grad=False)
tensor_5 = torch.randn((1, 16, 256, 256), requires_grad=False)
tensor_6 = torch.randn((1, 16, 256, 256), requires_grad=False)
tensor_7 = torch.randn((1, 16, 1024, 1024), requires_grad=False)
tensor_8 = torch.randn((1, 16, 1024, 1024), requires_grad=False)
tensor_9 = torch.randn((1, 16, 1024, 1024), requires_grad=False)

def quarternion_concat2(x,dim=1):
    output = torch.empty(tuple([i if I!=dim else i*len(x) for I,i in enumerate(x[0].shape)])) 
    inds = torch.arange(output.shape[dim]).reshape([-1,4*len(x)])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        output[:,inds[:,i*4:i*4+4].flatten()] = x[i]
    return output

def time_funcs(x,str,N=100):
    print(str)
    s = time()
    for _ in range(N):
        tensor4 = quarternion_concat(x, dim=1)
    print('First method: {:1.7f}'.format((time()-s)/1000))

    s = time()
    for _ in range(N):
        tensor5 = quarternion_concat2(x, dim=1)
    print('Second method: {:1.7f}'.format((time()-s)/1000))

time_funcs([tensor_1,tensor_2],'Two small')
time_funcs([tensor_1,tensor_2,tensor_3],'Three small')
time_funcs([tensor_4,tensor_5],'Two big')
time_funcs([tensor_4,tensor_5,tensor_6],'Three big')
time_funcs([tensor_7,tensor_8],'Two huge')
time_funcs([tensor_7,tensor_8,tensor_9],'Three huge')
```

I've tested the two functions using the functions above, which give the outputs:

```
Two small
First method: 0.0000057
Second method: 0.0000087
Three small
First method: 0.0000092
Second method: 0.0000123
Two big
First method: 0.0001286
Second method: 0.0000672
Three big
First method: 0.0003167
Second method: 0.0001077
Two huge
First method: 0.0101665
Second method: 0.0013700
Three huge
First method: 0.0154018
Second method: 0.0020662
```

As you can see, the method I've provided isn't quicker for very small inputs, unfortunately, but does scale really well for larger inputs. I hope it's of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer, I came up with a solution that utilizes `class` to compute the indices and use `index_select` to rearrange the concatenation. The only drawback is that the number of inputs and channels are required before execution.

```
import torch
from time import time


def quarternion_concat(x, dim=2):
    output = [[] for i in range(4)]
    for _x in x:
        sp = torch.chunk(_x, 4, dim=dim)
        for i in range(4):
            output[i].append(sp[i])

    final = []
    for o in output:
        o = torch.cat(o, dim)
        final.append(o)

    return torch.cat(final, dim)


tensor_1 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_2 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_3 = torch.randn((1, 16, 64, 64), requires_grad=False)
tensor_4 = torch.randn((1, 16, 256, 256), requires_grad=False)
tensor_5 = torch.randn((1, 16, 256, 256), requires_grad=False)
tensor_6 = torch.randn((1, 16, 256, 256), requires_grad=False)
tensor_7 = torch.randn((1, 16, 1024, 1024), requires_grad=False)
tensor_8 = torch.randn((1, 16, 1024, 1024), requires_grad=False)
tensor_9 = torch.randn((1, 16, 1024, 1024), requires_grad=False)


def quarternion_concat2(x, dim=1):
    output = torch.empty(tuple([i if I != dim else i * len(x) for I, i in enumerate(x[0].shape)])).cuda()
    # output = torch.cat(x, dim=dim)
    inds = torch.arange(output.shape[dim]).view([-1, 4 * len(x)]).cuda()
    for i in range(len(x)):
        output[:, inds[:, i * 4:i * 4 + 4].flatten()] = x[i]
    return output


class concat(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, no_of_inputs, total_number_of_channel):
        super().__init__()
        temp = torch.chunk(torch.arange(total_number_of_channel).view([-1, 4, 4]), no_of_inputs, dim=0)
        self.register_buffer('indx', torch.cat(temp, dim=2).flatten())

    def forward(self, x):
        output = torch.cat(x, dim=1).index_select(dim=1, index=self.indx)
        return output


def time_funcs(x, str, N=100):
    x = [i.cuda() for i in x]
    print(str)
    s = time()
    for _ in range(N):
        tensor4 = quarternion_concat(x, dim=1)
    print('First method: {:1.7f}'.format((time() - s) / 1000))

    s = time()
    for _ in range(N):
        tensor5 = quarternion_concat2(x, dim=1)
    print('Second method: {:1.7f}'.format((time() - s) / 1000))

    m = concat(len(x), 16 * len(x)).cuda()
    s = time()
    for _ in range(N):
        tensor6 = m(x)
    print('Third method: {:1.7f}'.format((time() - s) / 1000))


time_funcs([tensor_1, tensor_2], 'Two small')
time_funcs([tensor_1, tensor_2, tensor_3], 'Three small')
time_funcs([tensor_4, tensor_5], 'Two big')
time_funcs([tensor_4, tensor_5, tensor_6], 'Three big')
time_funcs([tensor_7, tensor_8], 'Two huge')
time_funcs([tensor_7, tensor_8, tensor_9], 'Three huge')
```

Below are the results when run on a GPU.

```
Two small
First method: 0.0000054
Second method: 0.0000203
Third method: 0.0000031
Three small
First method: 0.0000081
Second method: 0.0000295
Third method: 0.0000022
Two big
First method: 0.0000050
Second method: 0.0001637
Third method: 0.0000028
Three big
First method: 0.0000056
Second method: 0.0002477
Third method: 0.0000022
Two huge
First method: 0.0000051
Second method: 0.0025740
Third method: 0.0000028
Three huge
First method: 0.0000062
Second method: 0.0038824
Third method: 0.0000028
```

Comment: woah mine is so slow on your machine... glad that I pointed you in the right direction at least!

Comment: That's mostly because of the initializations. Also, the new code I wrote assumes that all tensors have the same number of channels. Currently, I am checking if that problem can be removed.